# function JavaScript retornando NaN

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia pessoal, feliz Páscoa!! Estou fazendo um curso de JavaScript com o Gustavo Guanabara e estou tento problemas no resultado da function em um exercício. Alguém por favor poderia me ajudar a achar o erro? obs: Minha primeira vez aqui na plataforma.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Verificador de idade</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p>
                Ano de Nascimento: 
                <input type="number" name="txtano" id="txtano">
            </p>
            <p>
                Sexo: 
                <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="mas" checked>
                <label for="masc">Masculino</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="fem">
                <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="verificar()">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="res"></div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>
            &copy; Todos os direitos reservados 2024
        </p>
    </footer>

    <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

    function verificar() {
        let data = new Date()
        let anoAtual = data.getFullYear()
        let fAno = document.getElementsByName('txtano')
        let res = window.document.querySelector('div#res')

        if (fAno == 0 || fAno > anoAtual) {
            window.alert ('Verifique os dados e tente novamente!')
        } else {
            let fSex = window.document.getElementsByName( 'radsex' )
            let idade = anoAtual - Number(fAno)
            res.innerHTML = `Idade calculada: ${idade}`
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDwb8.png)

Comment: In stack overflow, Posts must be written in English.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that Stackoverflow is English only. Please translate your question or use [Stackoverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com).